# Intersection on circle of vector originating inside circle

Tags: math, geometry

I have a circle. Inside the circle is a point. I have a vector originating at this point. I'd like to know what point on the circle this vector intersects. Here is a drawing:

[http://n4te.com/temp/circle.png http://n4te.com/temp/circle.png](http://n4te.com/temp/circle.png)

The red dot is the point I am trying to determine.

I know these things: the center of the circle, the origin of the vector, and the direction of the vector.

I know this is basic stuff, but I'm still having trouble. Most of the Googlings bring me to line-circle collision, which is related but not quite the same. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Linked image is gone, sorry. Was just a circle with a vector originating in it and intersecting the circle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Elementary vector algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector).

```
O — center of circle (vector)
r — its radius       (scalar)
A — origin of ray    (vector)
k — direction of ray (vector)
```

Solve `(A + kt - O)² = r²` for scalar `t`, choose positive root, and `A + kt` is your point.

**Further explanation:**

`.` is [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), ² for a vector is dot product of the vector with itself. Expand LHS

```
(A + kt - O)² = (A - O)² + 2(k.(A - O))t + k²t².
```

The quadratic is `k²t² + 2(k.(A - O))t + (A - O)² - r² = 0`. In terms of your variables, this becomes `(rayVX² + rayVY²)t² + 2(rayVX(rayX - circleX) + rayVY(rayY - circleY))t + (rayX - circleX)² + (rayY - circleY)² - r² = 0`.

Answer (score 11):

Much thanks to Anton Tykhyy for his detailed answer. This was the resulting Java code:

```
float xDiff = rayX - circleX;
float yDiff = rayY - circleY;
float a = rayVX * rayVX + rayVY * rayVY;
float b = 2 * (rayVX * (rayX - circleX) + rayVY * (rayY - circleY));
float c = xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff - r * r;
float disc = b * b - 4 * a * c;
if (disc >= 0) {
    float t = (-b + (float)Math.sqrt(disc)) / (2 * a);
    float x = rayX + rayVX * t;
    float y = rayY + rayVY * t;
    // Do something with point.
}
```